# Trying to add textbox dynamically to table when rows are added

Tags: javascript

I need to create a table using only JavaScript. The table is created dynamically so I can add extra rows if I needed too. However, each row on the table needs to have a text box.

When I try to do it this way (shown below) the table loads but says [object HTML Input Element] where the text box should be. I think it's because `element.innerHTML` is trying to change it to a string.

Can anyone help with another way to add the text box to the table?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {

  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  //element from array    

  //input box
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "text");

  cell1.innerHTML = "object.Section"; //adds content from array outside the loop
  cell2.innerHTML = document.body.appendChild(x); //adding text box
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to add some example HTML to get the snippet demo working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using innerHTML, use appendChild directly on cell2 like this: cell2.appendChild(x);

So, your code will be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {

  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  //element from array    

  //input box
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "text");

  cell1.innerHTML = "object.Section"; //adds content from array outside the loop
  cell2.appendChild(x); //adding text box
}
```